# WPF UserControl - Implement a usercontrol which changes displayed data based on it's size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to implement a WPF UserControl which displays 3 lists of "Image+Text"
(my view-model is a Zoo object which holds lists of animals by categories: mammals, reptiles and insects)

One very important capability of this control is that when the size of the window/dialog in which it will be used, is getting smaller, the control will be notified and under specific size it will show only images without text (I don't want to use scroll bar).

In addition if the number of animals under one category is longer than the control can show, once again -> the control should use only images and remove text.

How can I listen to changes in window size? 
How can I know that the user control got smaller or has less space to show itself?

Thanks for the help,
CL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a. "*How can I listen to changes in window size?*"

You can attach event handler to `SizeChanged` event of the UserControl.

```
private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var usrControlHeight = e.NewSize.Height;
    var usrControlWidth = e.NewSize.Width;
    //take action based on current UserControl size
}
```

> b. "*How can I know that the user control got smaller or has less space to show itself?*"

I'll take this as: you want to get notified when *the number of animals under one category is longer than the control can show*. You can put your logic to calculate total space/height needed to show all animals in list in the same event handler as above. Then compare calculation result with current UserControl's height, and take an action accordingly.